# Xamarin Tasky Project Error While Build Android Version App

Tags: android, xamarin, namespaces, resources, xamarin.forms

I have download from Xamarin Studio **Tasky** Project and open it

**with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition**

when i build  the Solution i got these Errors in **ANDROID** App

[image]

with knowledge that i didn't changed any thing yet in the project.

[image]

i tried to build and clean and rebuild the project but still the it gives me an error once i build it.

while iOS version is building and running perfectly

Comment: Can you point to the line where this error is occurring.

Comment: @ArunGupta Thanks, The Post Has Been Updated.

Comment: It seems missing a header file. Check if you have any missing header at top.

Answer (score 0):

Try right click on Android head > Properties > Choose Application panel. Compare the Namespace in Application panel of the Android project is equal with the namespace in the Resource Designer file (/Resources/Resource.Designer.cs). If not **don't** change this direct in Resource.Designer.cs file (because the file will be automatically generated). Instead, you can change the namespace in all affected files to the namespace you see in the Android Application panel or use 'using' in the affected files.

Comment: Thanks, Actually **Resource.Designer.cs** is empty with nothing inside it. !!

Comment: Okay, so remove the Resource.Designer.cs file from the project. Check the file is also deleted from storage. Clean your project and rebuild it; then the file should be regenerated. Now add the file to the project again. Check the Build Action is 'Compile' (sometimes it updates automatically to build action 'AndroidResource').

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to Android `SDK Platform` of target OS API version is not installed. Make sure you install all Android APIs SDK versions, specifically the one's you're targeting in `Project Settings` of Android in Visual Studio.
[image]

Open `Android SDK Manager` and revise the below

[image]

Once you install them, restart, then open VS and clean the build output and re-build everything.

Comment: Thanks api 17 and 19 Are Installed. and i target 17 devices. and the problem still

Answer (score 0):

So, After trying to solve this problem with many ways and all of it are not the optimal solution.

i Finally find the root Solution for this Issue.

**you should Uninstall any Android Build-Tools Which In The *Preview Chanel* in the Android SDK Manager.**

after doing so, clean and rebuild the Xamarin project.